# jQuery bounce not firing

Tags: jquery, bounce

This is what the bottom of hy head looks like:

```
$('#hello').mouseenter(function() {
$(this).effect("bounce", { times:1, distance:10 }, 800);
});
```

I'm linking to jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.8. I'm not getting any errors, but when I hover over the #hello div, nothing is happening.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you put the above code inside `$(document).ready(....`? It's working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/7dgaB/

Comment: Hi Joy, I figured it was some kind of a loading deal. I don't have the $(document).ready()
Googling.. Yup. That was it. Thanks!

Comment: Check the link above, and put that javascript instead. I am Adding an answer.

Comment: @VGD, proper thanks is to **Upvote** (This answer is useful) *and* **Accept** it when the answer solves your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You jQuery code seems fine, So it's most likely You have missed the `document ready` block

So add the `doc ready` handler like

```
$(function() {

    $('#hello').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).effect("bounce", {
            times: 1,
            distance: 30
        }, 800);
    });   
});​
```

It will ensure that that code will fire when `DOM` is ready.

If you just use `$("#hello").mouseenter(...)` without any `doc ready block`, then there  is a chance when this code will run, when there isn't any element with `id hello` in DOM yet. So `$("#hello")` will return an empty set and `mouseenter` binding won't work.

An example markup when it won't work without `doc ready block`,

```
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#hello").mouseenter(....);
</script>
.
.
.
.
<div id="hello">Blah Blah....</div>
```

As browsers, interprets the markup sequentially, it will execute the js code as soon as it face it. And when it executes the JS block here, it hasn't yet parsed the `<div id="hello">` tag yet, as it appears after the JS block, So they are not in DOM at that moment.

So for the above case `$("#hello")` is empty and hence event binding won't work. So it's always safe to put all your JS code inside `document ready` block like

```
$(function){
   // put all your JS code here
});
```

Read more http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks so much Joy. This was very helpful! Unfortunately I can't upvote just yet, but I'll bookmark this and get back when I can.